# How to filter after the mongodb database is saved successfully

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use mongoose to save the username and password to the database.
After saving successfully, i want to return this record to the client.
But I should not return a password.
How can I delete the specified attribute?

```
'use strict';

// POST https://example.com/api/v1/user
async create(postData) {
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
  const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
  });
  const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

  const UserEntity = new UserModel({
    username: postData.username,
    password: postData.password,
  });

  // save to Database
  const result = await UserEntity.save();
  // Only return username, no password returned
  if (result) {
    delete result.password;
  }

  return result;
  // console:
  //  {
  //  username: 'tom'
  //  password: '123456' // This property is still being returned.
  //  }
}
```

As you can see, The `delete` function does not work.
How should i fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `result` is mongoose document so you need to use `result = result.toJSON()` first then `delete result.password;` will work as expected.

Comment: How did you call `result.toJSON()`? Is that `result = result.toJSON()` or just `result.toJSON()`? It need to be `result = result.toJSON()`.